# OpenDocument spreadsheet corrupt in Microsoft Excel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, libreoffice-calc, ods

I am using a gem to write to an OpenDocument spreadsheet ([RSpreadsheet](https://github.com/gorn/rspreadsheet)).
Once the data is written I let the user download it. The spreadsheet works fine in OpenOffice Calc and Numbers for Mac. However, when I try to open the spreadsheet in Microsoft Excel it tells me the spreadsheet is corrupt. This only happens when I write data to it. I can open it via Ruby and save it as it is and it will work fine. Once I write data to it, it becomes corrupt.

I have tried another gem ([Rubiod](https://github.com/netoctone/rubiod)) and was able to open the spreadsheet in Excel but only after Excel had to 'recover' the spreadsheet. In doing so it removed the formulas and some formatting. It was even worse in OpenOffice and Numbers although it did retain the formulas.

I need the user to be able to download this spreadsheet in whichever program they choose. I have no idea why Excel says the sheet is corrupt and have tried to wrap my head around it for hours.

The spreadsheet is saved with the .ODS extension and downloaded using the MIME type of `application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet` and a character set of `utf-8`

Examples:

```
original = Rspreadsheet.open 'blank.ods'
sheet = original.worksheets 1
sheet.A1 = 'FooBar' # Without this, Excel can open the spreadsheet fine
original.save 'new.ods'

respond_to do |format|
  format.all do
    send_data File.read('new.ods'), type: 'application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet; charset=utf-8; header=present' disposition: 'attachment; filename=new.ods'
  end
end
```